# Requirements for a welldefined, lineare and injective function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am totally clueless here so any help is really appreciated.

> Let $ \mu$ be a measure on a topological space $X$. Let $Y$ be a banach space.
>   I am given the function $$ g:C(X, Y ) \longrightarrow L^p(X,\mu,Y)/ker\|.\|_p$$   $$f \longmapsto [f]$$

I have showed already that $L^p(X,\mu,Y)/ker\|.\|_p$ is a normed space.

Now I need to find assumptions so that the given function is a **well-defined**, **linear** and **injective function**

Comment: I didn’t understand your question. Explain it little bit more.

Comment: @MayureshL i have edited the question a bit. Hopefully it is more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is compact topological space and $ \mu(X)< \infty$ then $g$ is well defined (if we remove one of these condition then we can construct continuous function whose $L^p$ norm is not finite).

It is easy to check that $g$ is linear.

Now to find assumptions under which $g$ is injective,

Let $f$, $h$ $\in C(X,Y)$ s.t. $f\not=h$

Hence there exist open subset $V$ of $X$ on which

$f(x)\not=h(x)$ for all $x\in V$.

Now if $\mu(V) >0$ then $g(f)\not= g(h)$ i.e. $[f] \not = [h]$.

Hence if we assume $\mu(U) > 0$ for all open subsets $U$ of  $X$ then $g$ is injective.

Comment: Wow thank you this helped me alot